# Entities in X participate in the Y relationship. 0 related Target were found. 1 Target is expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys, table-per-type

I am having an issue with a 1:0..1 relationship.  I get the error: Entities in 'TestContext.Environments' participate in the 'PortalEnvironment_BaEnvironment' relationship. 0 related 'PortalEnvironment_BaEnvironment_Target' were found. 1 'PortalEnvironment_BaEnvironment_Target' is expected.

I have 3 tables, implementing Table-Per-Type.

Below is the simplified version of the SQL / C# code I am using for my test:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EnvironmentBase(
    EnvironmentId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.BAEnvironment(
    EnvironmentId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    CONSTRAINT FK_BAEnvironment_EnvironmentBase FOREIGN KEY(EnvironmentId) 
        REFERENCES dbo.EnvironmentBase (EnvironmentId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.PortalEnvironment(
    EnvironmentId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    BAEnvironmentId int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PortalEnvironment_BAEnvironment FOREIGN KEY(BAEnvironmentId) 
        REFERENCES dbo.BAEnvironment (EnvironmentId) ,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PortalEnvironment_EnvironmentBase FOREIGN KEY(EnvironmentId) 
        REFERENCES dbo.EnvironmentBase (EnvironmentId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

While working through my issues, I used used the following article to help out [One to Zero/One Relationship in EF](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/806344/one-to-zero-one-relation-in-entity-framework-code) utilizing Option2Mimic (independent association) as that seems to be the most appropriate for my situation.  However, I get the error shown above.

POCOs:

```
public abstract partial class Environment
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // EnvironmentId (Primary key)

    public Environment()
    {
        InitializePartial();
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();
}

public partial class BaEnvironment : Environment
{
    // MAY have a portal environment
    public virtual PortalEnvironment PortalEnvironment { get; set; } // PortalEnvironment.FK_PortalEnvironment_BAEnvironment

    public BaEnvironment()
    {
        InitializePartial();
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();
}

public partial class PortalEnvironment : Environment
{
    // MUST have a BAMS environment
    public virtual BaEnvironment BaEnvironment { get; set; } // PortalEnvironment.FK_PortalEnvironment_BAEnvironment

    public PortalEnvironment()
    {
        InitializePartial();
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();
}
```

Configurations:

```
public partial class EnvironmentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Environment>
{
    public EnvironmentMap() : this("dbo")
    {
    }

    public EnvironmentMap(string schema)
    {
        ToTable("EnvironmentBase", schema);
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName(@"EnvironmentId")
            .HasColumnType("int").IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.Ordinal).HasColumnName(@"Ordinal")
            .HasColumnType("tinyint").IsRequired();

        InitializePartial();
    }
    partial void InitializePartial();
}

public partial class BaEnvironmentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<BaEnvironment>
{
    public BaEnvironmentMap() : this("dbo")
    {
    }

    public BaEnvironmentMap(string schema)
    {
        ToTable("BAEnvironment", schema);

        InitializePartial();
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();
}

public partial class PortalEnvironmentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PortalEnvironment>
{
    public PortalEnvironmentMap() : this("dbo")
    {
    }

    public PortalEnvironmentMap(string schema)
    {
        ToTable("PortalEnvironment", schema);
        //Property(x => x.BaEnvironmentId).HasColumnName(@"BAEnvironmentId")
            .HasColumnType("int").IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        // Foreign keys
        HasRequired(a => a.BaEnvironment).WithOptional(b => b.PortalEnvironment)
            .Map(c => c.MapKey(@"BAEnvironmentId"));

        InitializePartial();
    }
    partial void InitializePartial();
}
```

I don't seem to be having any problem with the TPT, just with the relationship between PortalEnvironment and BAEnvironment.  The relationship between BAEnvironment and PortalEnvironment is 1:0..1, therefore a BAEnviroment MAY have an associated PortalEnvironment, but ALL PortalEnvironments MUST have an associated BAEnvironment.

My problem seems very simple, but I have been going back and forth and just not hitting the right combinations of fluent api to solve it.

It's worth noting that I am a DBA, not an app developer.  Just being stuck with this because nobody else will do it.

Comment: The first thing I find it interesting is a table with 1 column, Why?

Comment: Why do you have Foreign Key _and_ Inheritance relationships among these entities?  That is . . . unusual.

Comment: @David The PortalEnvironment and BAEnvironment have some of the same features, but each have many other properties that the other does not, therefore the inheritance.  There are actually several more TPT classes, I am just focusing on these, because the relationship between these two is the problem.  I'm not having any problems with the inheritance itself.

Comment: @Sami These are just test tables, which focus only on the problem.  In actuality, each of the tables has several more columns.

Answer (score 0):

EF6 does not support alternate keys, and so requires that the a foreign key column be the Entity Key in a 1..1 relationship.  You can mark the FK as being unique, but in the EF model you will still have a 1..many relationship between BAEnvironment and Portal Environment.

Eg

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ef6Test
{

    public abstract partial class Environment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } // EnvironmentId (Primary key)

        public Environment()
        {
            InitializePartial();
        }

        partial void InitializePartial();
    }

    public partial class BaEnvironment : Environment
    {
        // MAY have a portal environment
        [InverseProperty("BaEnvironment")]
        public virtual ICollection<PortalEnvironment> PortalEnvironments { get; } = new HashSet<PortalEnvironment>();

        public BaEnvironment()
        {
            InitializePartial();
        }

        partial void InitializePartial();
    }

    public partial class PortalEnvironment : Environment
    {
        // MUST have a BAMS environment
        [ForeignKey("BaEnvironmentID")]
        public virtual BaEnvironment BaEnvironment { get; set; } // PortalEnvironment.FK_PortalEnvironment_BAEnvironment

        [Required(), Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public int BaEnvironmentID { get; set; }

        public PortalEnvironment()
        {
            InitializePartial();
        }

        partial void InitializePartial();
    }
    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Environment> Environment { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BaEnvironment> BaEnvironment { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PortalEnvironment> PortalEnvironment { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Environment>().ToTable("Environment");
            modelBuilder.Entity<BaEnvironment>().ToTable("BaEnvironment");
            modelBuilder.Entity<PortalEnvironment>().ToTable("PortalEnvironment");

            modelBuilder.Entity<PortalEnvironment>().HasRequired<BaEnvironment>(e => e.BaEnvironment).WithMany();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }




    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());

            using (var db = new Db())
            {

                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                db.Database.Initialize(true);


            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have left the unique constraint out of that model.  It's not really relevant to the issue I am having, since it is the source not, the target.

Comment: It's certainly relevant.  If PortalEnvironment.BAEnvironmentId is not UNIQUE, then multiple PortalEnvironment rows could refer to the same BAEnvironment row, and the releationship would be 1..Many.

EF requires that a 1-1 relationship use a Key as the Foreign Key, and EF6 only supports one Key per Entity.

Comment: What I mean is that I don't even get that far.  My original test model does NOT have the unique constraint.  It doesn't even compile without giving the error.  Therefore, the constraint is not relevant to my current problem.  I will get around to looking closer to your solution tomorrow.  Thanks!